# Hibernate 6 / JPA - how to update smallint column with fixed value?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an update that works like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Entity set smallintCol = 1 where id = :id")
void doUpdate(@Param("id") int id)
```

When upgrading to Hibernate 6.1 thru Spring Boot 3, validation fails for this query because 1 is integer and the column is short.

This doesn't work:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Entity set smallintCol = ((short) 1) where id = :id")
void doUpdate(@Param("id") int id)
```

How would I do this update?

Edit:

I am using PosgreSQL

The error that is issued is when booting spring:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: The assignment expression type [java.lang.Integer] did not match the assignment path type [java.lang.Short] for the path [alias_861886687.qtTentativasEnvio]
```

Column is mapped as:

```
@Column(name = "qt_tentativas_envio", nullable = false)
private short qtTentativasEnvio;
```

Comment: You have not shown: (1) the error message or stack trace, (2) the mapped `Entity` class, (3) which database you are using, so it's simply impossible to help you in any way. What I can tell you is that `((short) 1)` is definitely not the right syntax for a typecast in HQL.

Comment: OK, thanks, your update has the needed info. I've confirmed this, and I opened  issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15939 because it seems to me that perhaps the HQL typechecker is being a little too fussy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
@Query("update Entity set smallintCol = cast(1 as short) where id = :id")
```

Comment: I feel stupid for not trying this before.